# Force Feign NOT to use https

Tags: http, feign

I use an API I can only call over HTTP. The HTTPS version is a premium service. If I call the HTTPS version I get an HTTP 200 but the json in response only contains an error message.

Is there a way I can force my Feign client to use HTTP and not HTTPS ?

Comment: If feign is a http client, can you just literally point to the `http` endpoint? Presumably you specified a url somewhere?

Comment: I am guessing you have found this already, but if not - https://nullbeans.com/how-to-configure-openfiegn-clients-to-perform-http-requests/